# Active Record Clear instance of model after_find callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have defined a callback after_find for checking some settings based on the retrieved instance of the model. If the settings aren't fulfilled I don't want the instance to be return from the find method. Is that possible?

an example 
the controller looks like:

```
class UtilsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @util = Util.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

the model:

```
class Util < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :valid_util_setting

  def valid_util_setting
    # calculate_availability? complex calculation 
    # that can not be part of the sql statement or a scope 

    unless self.setting.calculate_availability?(User.current.session)
      #if not available => clear the record for view
    else
      #nothing to do here
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Dont know if it will work, but did u try setting `self` to `nil` ?

Comment: @Neo - That won't work as you can't change the value of self

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35428/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18230173-active-record-clear-instance-of-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
def valid_util_setting
  Object.const_get(self.class.name).new().attributes.symbolize_keys!.each do |k,v| 
    begin
      self.assign_attributes({k => v})#, :without_protection => true)
    rescue ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error => e; end
  end
end
```

With this I'm able to create an almost empty object

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to clear the record, you could just raise an exception?

E.g.

```
unless self.setting.calculate_availability?(User.current.session)
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
else
...
```

Comment: This won't do it, because if I want all available utils and there is one not available, then I will get an exception and not the resultset without that one element

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't clear found record in this callback
Maybe you should find in scope with all your options from the beginning?
I.e. `@util = Util.scoped.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I have to work a little bit further, but as I said atm I can't create a scope from the calculation.

Comment: what conditions are needed to check?

Comment: I need the callback from another service if the system has enough resources and the host of the service depends from the util

Comment: ok. so maybe not to be so 'clear-coded' and to make just some lib function or something like it to call for example so `MyLib.check(Util.find(params[:id]))` that will return nil if needed

Comment: Problem here, I can't access all the software parts to change the behaviour to this

Comment: then I see the solution - to override find method in Util model. `def self.find(args*)` and so on. It's not the best practice, but maybe will help

Comment: This won't do it. I found my answer, but it isn't best practice anyway